# VHDL simulation 'X' output (Vivado)

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, vhdl, design, vivado

I'm trying to build a modulo-4 counter using dataflow modeling. I devised the logic circuit like the following;

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEsHA9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I wanted to implement this circuit with VHDL. I started from building an SR-latch. Then, a D-latch, then, a DFF. Finally I used the DFFs to build the circuit.

Following is my VHDL code for the counter,

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity mod4_counter is
  Port (CLK : in std_logic; COUT : out std_logic);
end mod4_counter;

architecture Behavioral of mod4_counter is
component d_flipflop is
  Port (DFF,CLK : in std_logic; QFF,QFFNOT : out std_logic );
end component;

signal dff1d, dff1q, dff1qnot, dff2d, dff2q, dff2qnot : std_logic;
begin
DFF1 : d_flipflop port map(DFF=>dff1d, CLK=>CLK, QFF=>dff1q, 
QFFNOT=>dff1qnot);
DFF2 : d_flipflop port map(DFF=>dff2d, CLK=>CLK, QFF=>dff2q, QFFNOT=>dff2qnot);
dff1d <= dff1q xor dff2q;
dff2d <= dff2qnot;
COUT <= dff1q and dff2q;
end Behavioral;
```

And the testbench code,

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity counter_sim is
end counter_sim;

architecture Behavioral of counter_sim is
component mod4_counter is
  Port (CLK : in std_logic; COUT : out std_logic );
end component;

signal CLK : std_logic;
signal COUT : std_logic;
begin
uut : mod4_counter port map(CLK=>CLK, COUT=>COUT);

clkpr : process
begin
CLK <= '1';
wait for 75ns;
CLK <= '0';
wait for 75ns;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

All the underlying components (SR, D latch, DFF) were simulated successfully. But when I simulate this design, COUT is always 'X'. What is wrong here?

Comment: 1/ The actual core of your code is the `d_flipflop` the code for which is missing. 2/ You probably do not give the register an initial value. 3/ This problem/question appears about once or twice  a month. Did you search for previous questions/answers?

Comment: @Oldfart Yes, I did a search about this issue on the internet. I was suspecting this might be an initial value problem. However, even if I assign a default value to ''COUT'', it still doesn't work. The d_flipflop code is not shared here because it functioned correctly during its simulation, so I assumed it was not the issue here.

Comment: Dude, you are missing reset thats why..Also adding init value to COUT does nothing cz it is driven by another net

Answer (score 1):

If you are only trying to implement your circuit then to me it seems that you are over thinking this: first let’s give **NAME** to the different signals:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSptVF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, let’s right the equations that rules the circuit:

> s_3 = s_1 XOR s_2
>
> s_4 = NOT s_2
>
> s_out = s_1 AND s_2

Now, let's write the code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL; 


entity counter_whatever is

    Port(
        i_clock   :  in std_logic;
        i_reset   :  in std_logic;
        o_result  : out std_logic
        );
end entity;


architecture Behavioural of counter_whatever is

    signal   s_1, s_2  :  std_logic;

begin

    --the output is not synchronous according to your schematic
    o_result <= s_1 AND s_2;


    --Process that deal with the upper register 
    uper_register : process(i_clock, i_reset)
        variable v_3 :  std_logic; 
    begin
        if rising_edge(i_clock) then

            --if a reset occurs
            if i_reset = '1' then
                v_3 := '0';
                s_1 <= '0';
            
            --if no reset occurs
            else
                v_3 := s_1 XOR s_2;
                s_1 <= v_3;
            
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;


    --Process that deal with the lower register 
    lower_register : process(i_clock, i_reset)
        variable v_4  :  std_logic; 
    begin
        if rising_edge(i_clock) then

            --if a reset occurs
            if i_reset = '1' then
                v_4 := '0';
                s_2 <= '0';
            
            --if no reset occurs
            else
                v_4 := NOT s_2;
                s_2 <= v_4;
            
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
end architecture;
```

You can remove the variables, I have added them for more clarity. You can also merge the 2 processes into a single one.

You should have a reset in your process.

I do not understand why you are talking about `SR-latch`, `D-latch` or `DFF`. In your schematic there is juste register (Flip-Flop).

Hope it helps you